# PHP send data directly to GCM without register_ids of the devices?

Tags: php, android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to send data from PHP server to all devices registered in the Google Cloud Messaging app without registering the ids of the devices in the PHP server db?

If not in PHP, is there other way to achieve this?

And one more question..
Which technology should I use to connect PHP Server with the GCM backend for manipulating a datastructure (within Cloud Datastore if necesary) that Android/IOS clients could subscribe to in order to receive PushNotification?

Comment: you are asking to successfully send the gift to someone without knowing the `address`.

Comment: yes but i can register the device id within the android backend. So when i have f.ex. 10 devices registered in the GCM app, is it possible to get these ids without registering them in php db, or is it possible to send the data to the GCM app and then it handle the request and send to all the registered devices?

Comment: what do you mean by `android backend`? Google is offering you GCM server for `just sending data on your behalf` using your `GCMKey(senderId) and RegIds of devices`.you need to command GCMServer to send the data to particular devices which have registered for your app and thats why you need to save their `RegIds` on your server.

Comment: Okay maybe I didnt get it right then..
I have followed the Mobile Backend Starter google tutorial and I have deployed an app, then I run the Android client and when I send a message it is registered to the app in the GCM. I can see there the device id and I was wondering if there is a way to send a message to all of these registered devices via php without registering in my db, but now if I understand correctly the ids registered in the GCM are there so when I send from php, the GCM will know to who to send form its own regs. Thanks :D